# MIxed Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi3, kubernetes-cluster

Good afternoon to all. I'm learning to use Kubernetes, so please be patient with me.

I was wondering if I can add any kind of server to a Kubernetes cluster, specifically an RPi as a worker/master? The intention would be to have a mixed cluster of laptops and RPis, with an RPi setup as a master as well. I understand that RPr 3B+ does not work very well with K8S... does that mean that the entire cluster setup would have to be running with K3S/Micro K8S?

I understand my question is a bit vague, so don't hesitate to LMK and I'll try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick one and *only one* k8s distribution that would work with the **smallest node** in your cluster. Example since you knew RPi is in the picture, your best bet will be k0s/k3s/microk8s as these distros are design for such devices. If all nodes have at least 64bit OS/2CPU/2GB **freely** available, you can start with upstream k8s.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Is there one that you recommend? I'm currently watching videos on the diff on K3S vs K8S... didn't even know there was a K0S!

Comment: There's a [running on raspberry pi](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-kubernetes-cluster-on-raspberry-pi?_ga=2.235181185.1098064532.1632205887-726396650.1628849426#1-overview) tutorial from microk8s. To help the next person with similar question, consider mark the comment as the answer.